# Start node js child process as admin

Tags: node.js, windows, child-process, spawn

Im trying to spawn a child process in node js from windows 10. I want to spawn this child process as admin. How can i do this ?? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to run this:-

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c cd p:\test && command -argument'"
```